# Can't read Arduino's serial output

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino

I'm making my first steps in `Arduino` programming and noticed that serial output working only with the default serial console that came with the `Arduino` software

This is my Arduino Code:

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(13 , OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop ()
{
  if (Serial.available()> 0)
  {
      Serial.println("Hello World");
      char Letter = Serial.read();
      if (Letter == '1')
      {
            digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
      }
      else if (Letter = '0')
      {
            digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      }
  }
}
```

And for the PC side I'm using the MSDN console application which is working for for any other device I've used before.
 [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(VS.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28VS.90%29.aspx)

All I want for now is for it to print the "Hello World" when property has changed.

Now when I using the Arduino's own serial console every thing works well.

I've checked that the Baud-rate and port are correct, and other settings I've left on default.

What can be the problem ??

Comment: What does it do? What error do you get?

Comment: I get no error , I can tell that the arduino get the input but I cant read its output

Comment: @Jeff OK I've checked it using SecureCRT and PuTTY (PLink) and it works , any other open source / free serial terminal application DOESN'T WORK

Comment: I dont use SecureCRT or PuTTY. I usually use Bray's Terminal. It looks to me like it should work. Does the LED change when you send 0s and 1s?

Comment: @Jeff Yes ! , In the meanwhile I've created a console application that runs Plink(PuTTY) as process , But what can be the problem ?